# Update an already existing field MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I was just wondering, how do you modify an already existing field from the command line in my sql. I have a foreign key which is appearing as MUL for some reason, and I want to try and reference it to a primary key of another. I had originally tried to do this from MYSQL Workbench and thus I think I have done something wrong.

Comment: For specific answers, please add the table schema & a query you've already tried, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the alter table syntax. You will probably need

```
alter table ... drop index
alter table ... add foreign key ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html